# Is it possible to make URLEncoder.encode not to replace = sign?

Tags: java

This is my sample program .

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String str = "KzhHqV77/SG+F0S7sGOZrw==";

        str = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");

        System.out.println(str);

    }

}
```

Is it possible to tell URLEncoder.encode not to replace = sign ??

Comment: Is your question really how to tell the URLEncoder to not do what it is supposed to do (replacing unsafe characters, of which '=' is one)? That does nto make sense.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? `=` in the URL is used to separate the name-value pairs in the query.

Comment: If = is not encoded --> URLEncoder is not its self.  Build your own encoder.

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty solution. "=" will be converted in "%3D", so just translate them back to "=":

```
URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8").replaceAll("%3D", "=")
```

ofc, if original string contains "%3D" this will not work well